# Is there a way of sending confidential mails via any coding language?

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

**Confidential mode** is a new feature introduced in gmail where the mail gets *destroyed after a certain time period*. So, can this feature be implemented via any of the coding languages for e.g. **phpmailer** or **swiftmailer**

Comment: Have you checked their doucmentation? Asked the developers?

Comment: Chances are it's just a variation of the [`Sensitivity:` header](https://people.dsv.su.se/~jpalme/ietf/mail-headers/mail-headers.html). Inspect 'le source mail and find out.

Answer (score 0):

[Confidential mode](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7674059?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1) is something that is built into Googles Mobile applications.

This feature would not have anything to do with coding language but rather with how an application would be built.  I dont see any reason why you couldn't build a feature like this into any application you wish.

As to whether or not this feature is part of [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) I think you would have to consult the developers on those projects.